# Why can't I install lldb in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, lldb

I want to set breakpoint during JNI, but when I edit my configurations, I can't install lldb plugin.

[image: Press fix button but does not have any effect]

[image: there is no lldb]

Any one can help me?
Android studio: 2.1.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LLDB is now available through the SDK Manager integrated into Android Studio which is under settings in Android studio and not through the standalone sdk manager.

To install it you have to Goto setting > Android SDK.

There under the SDK Tools you have LLDB, select the checkbox and install it.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks Radix!. My final solution is change the proxy.  Android Studio - > Preferences -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> HTTP Proxy.  And chose "Auto-detect proxy settings". And then set my proxy.

Comment: Like OP, I suffer from "no lldb in the list of installable items".  I have Android Studio 4.0, built on May 20, '20 (last week), running on Mac.

(Does it, perhaps, recognize that I already have lldb, thanks to Xcode?)

Screenshot: http://www.manyfriends.com/misc/no-lldb.png

Comment: Do I, perhaps, need to add a download source for it?

Comment: From the official docs: " By default, LLDB will be installed alongside Android Studio."
Seems like something to do with your AS installation. I use Jetbrains Toolbox to install AS. Maybe try that and install the Android SDK from scratch.

Comment: @Olie same pblm for me