# How to get LLDB in Android Studio? (Not listed in the SDK Tools)

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, lldb

I'm using Android studio 4.0.1, I need to install LLDB as one of the requirements for the Dlib library, As you can see [here](https://medium.com/@luca_anzalone/setting-up-dlib-and-opencv-for-android-3efdbfcf9e7f). I open the SDK Manager (Tools -> SDK Manager) in Android studio, Go to the SDK Tools Tab, and there is no LLDB.

I tried (As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37639998/why-cant-i-install-lldb-in-android-studio/37644651)) to access the SDK Manager under File -> Settings and it is not there also. I used Android studio version 3.6 before and came across this issue, so i completely uninstalled Android studio version 3.6 and installed Android studio version 4.0.1 from scratch (including the SDK), and the problem is here again. I still don't see LLDB in the SDK Tools.

It doesn't seem like a bug in Android studio, LLDB is not available in versions 3.6 and 4.0.1, and I'm pretty sure it will not help to reinstall Android studio again.

Is there another way to get LLDB installed for Android studio (on Windows)?

My SDK Tools screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mine also does not have that option!
I will share what I found until someone comes with a better answer.

As far as I am aware, LLDB is now the default and only debugger of Android Studio. Therefore it does not appear as an option anymore because it is part of Android Studio.

My references:
https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/gdb ,it states:

"For app development, see Debug your app instead, which explains how to use the Android Studio GUI (based on LLDB)."

In https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index for example is stated:

"Native (available only with C/C++ code)Select this debug type if you want to use only LLDB to debug your code."

**This page makes many references just to lldb to debug  native C++ code. But never mentions gdb anywhere. Just that alone, should somehow let us know that gdb is out of the game.**

But digging further:

Interesting is, that if we look at Android Studio release notes webpage at:
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases#2-0-0

it is never mentioned that gdb was replaced by lldb or that the option for gdb does not exist anymore.

(But there is some interesting release note from android studio 3.1 that LLDB only works for android studio 4.1 (strange). )

However if we check the Android NDK ( which is used to compile native C++ in android studio) release notes history, at: https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/revision_history

it is stated for example at Revision r22b (March 2021)
"ndk-gdb now uses lldb as the debugger ".

**and at Android NDK, Revision r18b (September 2018) states: "GCC has been removed"!!!!!!!**

It would be great to find a webpage/release note information that clearly states what you are asking in regard to Android Studio.
It should have been mentioned in the android studio releases notes something like "GDB was replaced by LLDB" or "GDB option was removed". was this note missed by the developers?. I do not know.

As such, I, like you, I am not 100% assured what happened to the GDB option, and when it was removed or if it was really removed.

Btw, i do not understand why it was completely replaced, and not left as an option.(and so called experts i asked also didn't had a definite answer either :)

Answer (score 0):

LLDB no longer needs to be installed separately in android studio. I can debug c++ code normally after installing NDK.